# Mac mini stuck in boot (progress bar full) after SSD Upgrade

Tags: mac, time-machine, startup, ssd, mac-mini

I've done the following:

- created a time machine backup from a mac mini with a 1TB HDD (only used about 40GB).
- replaced the disk with a previously used, working SSD - Samsung EVO 850, 500GB.
- time machine restore - seemed to go smooth.
- booted up the machine.

Current state is Progress bar full with apple logo, stuck all night.

I've done a verbose boot, and could see the following errors:

```
localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds) <Notice>: Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out for 10 seconds.
```

Trying to load in single user mode gives the following errors:

```
failed to locate mount-on path: /private/var/vm Failed to mount vm volume (2)
failed to mount vm volume!BootCache: Root disk is an SSD, not caching
```

If there is any way to extract errors from the log, I could post them here.

[EDIT] -  I did try formatting the SSD before trying the 4th time to restore from backup. This failed as well.

Let me know in the comments if I can improve my question.

Comment: Can you capture a slow-motion (high speed) video of the entire verbose boot process and upload framegrabs of full pages of text so that we can inspect the boot log more closely?

Comment: Also what macOS version are you running?

Comment: I tried that - but had issues uploading it. ultimately I did a workaround (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error - managed to solve it.
I don't know why the time machine backup didn't work - but this workaround fixed it:

- Installed a fresh copy of mac OS X on the mac mini, only after first formatting the SSD with GUID Partition table scheme.
- Once the OS was installed, the time-machine backup worked on first try.